# How can I extract fonts from a PDF file with Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, fonts

Is there a script to extract the embedded fonts from a PDF file?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF), one of the several popular Perl PDF libraries.  Included in my package is a [tool to list embedded fonts](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?listfonts.pl) in a document, but I have not built any support for extracting fonts.  That would probably be used primarily for **copyright violation**, so I'm not interested in supporting such a feature.

Comment: No, it could be used for a copyright violation.  You can also buy a hammer and murder someone with it, but still, hammers are manufactured.

Comment: @Svante: If you want a non-copyrighted font, then you just download it -- you don't need to extract it from the PDF.  By your analogy, the questioner is asking for lockpicks to acquire a hammer: it seems highly suspicious.

In your comment you said "buy".  The questioner did not ask what's the URL for a website where s/he can buy fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I just googled and found there resources. I think it might be useful to you.

[PDF PERL](http://www.misc-perl-info.com/pdf-perl.html)